# writing a program to print "invalid input" when a closing parentheses ")" doesn't have a beginning open parentheses "("

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
str=")(hi)(hello))"

lcount=0
rcount=0
for i in str:
    print(i)
    if i == "(":
        lcount+=1
    if i == ")":
        rcount+=1
print(lcount, rcount)

if lcount == rcount:
    print("there's an even number of ( and )s")

if i[0] == ")":
    print("invalid input")
```

right now i can make it so that it will print "invalid input" when the first character is a closing bracket, but i can't get it to work for all that don't have a corresponding (

Comment: You really only need one variable that you count up for left, down for right, and if it's non-zero then you know you have invalid input.  Is the example you gave working or failing?

Comment: Initialize a variable, let's call it `paren_depth`, to 0.  Add 1 to it every time you see an opening parentheses, and subtract 1 every time you see a closing parentheses.  If the variable ever goes negative, or if it is greater than zero at the end of the input, the parens are mismatched.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I suggested (plus realizing what @JohnGordon is telling you when I wrote the code):

```
str=")(hi)(hello))"                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
count = 0                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
for i in str:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
    if i == "(":                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
        count += 1                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
    elif i == ")":                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
        count -= 1
    if count < 0:
        break                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
if count == 0:                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
    print("there's an even number of ( and )s")                                                                                                                                                                                              
else:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
    print("invalid input")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if i[0] == ")":
    print("invalid input")
```

The code snippet **above** checks the variable `i[0]`, which in this case stores the latest & last character in the `for` loop above. Which in your case would store `)` and the "invalid input" statement will be printed, this statement will be printed as long as you end your input string with `)`. Which I believe is something you do not want.

```
if lcount == rcount and mystr[0] != ")":
    print("there's an even number of ( and )s")
else:
    print("invalid input")
```

*Assuming that you are checking for the first character if it starts with an open bracket*, make the change in variable as you can see above. Also, I highly recommend **avoiding** the variable `str` when naming your variable.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another possible soluton:

```
string = ")(hi)(hello))"

# Count left and right parentheses, then compare the result
# Raise a ValueError (with a custom message) if counts aren't equal.
if string.count("(") != string.count(")"):
    raise ValueError("Unbalanced parentheses detected!")
```

Also, don't use `str`, `list`, `bool`, etc., as variable names and that can cause confusion and havoc.